# Handle layouts for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 for the same app

Tags: ios, uiview

I am facing issue in layouts while handling view for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. I don't understand the purpose autolayout as it never adjusted the frame according to the screen size. I have tried using free form but it didn't work.

This code is perfect for iPhone 4 but for iPhone 5 do i have to adjust the frame in the code by using UIScreen size?

I will request you to suggest the autolayout functionality as this should have worked.

Comment: How are you creating / setting the constraints? Setting when when you are using autolayouts is a smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewDidLoad

```
CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);

if(!CGSizeEqualToSize(screenSize, self.view.bounds.size)) {

    NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
    [self updateLayouts];
}
```

here's the definition

```
-(void) updateLayouts {

    float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    float screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, screenWidth, screenHeight);
}
```

It does adjust their subviews. It's working as expected. But I have not managed to handle it with autoLayout.

Comment: There must be a reason why it doesn't work for you automatically. You won't need this code otherwise. Layout is tricky, constraints are unstable and can easily get broken. You need to provide more information to get help here.

Answer (score 3):

- Tell iOS that your app is iPhone 5 ready by creating an appropriate image for
  launch screen (Default-568h@2x.png 640x1136).
- Use auto layout.

Your xib will automatically reflect the device screen size.

Comment: I have added launch image already in my plist. It's working but the view controller views didn't adjust their frames when i av used autolayout. Thanks though.